# phonegap build cordova.file is undefined

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am trying to build phonegap app using File plugin, it works fine on local , but when building it using Phonegap build , the plugin does not work, error is 
"cordova.file" is undefined
here is my config

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" />
```

- I removed (verion number=1.0.1) as adviced by other questions

Also phonegap build says: "This app isn't using the latest version of PhoneGap. We recommend upgrading to 3.6.3."

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look docs:

> Add the following to your config.xml to use version 1.0.1 of this plugin (recommended)::

```
      <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" version="1.0.1" />
```

> You can also omit the version tag to always use the most recent version of this plugin. Note that this will result in your app being automatically updated with new versions of this plugin as they are released, and may result in unexpected behaviour.

This is why you can run your app locally that not doing update automatically, however when make build, then it always try to update to the latest plugin version but your PhoneGap platform still with plugin 1.0.1 version, then `undefined` happen.

So to remove `version` tag, you should garantee your current plugin version is latest

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap has problem with file plugin new features in versions later than 1.0.1
so I worked around this by including the Javascript files in the pages
thanks